# How do I check the printer status?

Tags: c#, printing

How do I check the printer is online (ready for printing) or not? Here is my code below,

```
string allPrinters = "";
foreach (string printname in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    allPrinters += printname;
    /* ## */
}
```

And I want to put the condition on my code to check the status on the "##" marked position on my code above. Like below:

```
if (/* Condition */)
{
    allPrinters += " [Online]\n";
}
else
{
    allPrinters += " [Offline]\n";
}
```

What will be the condition? I tried with some similar kind of stackoverflow solutions but not working for me. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: just refer [click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6069/How-to-Check-if-your-Printer-is-Connected-using-C)

Comment: @SubhojitMukherjee Click on hector's link

Comment: Hector's link is an example of using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I think you are both saying the right things but I am newbie in C#. Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: I tried this and getting an error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type" `printer["WorkOffline"]`